# Is there a way to turn a array into a integer or float?

Tags: arrays, parsing, integer, julia

I'm trying to change an array with int into a single int in Julia 1.5.4 like that:

```
x = [1,2,3]
```

Here i would try or use a code/command (here: example())

```
x_new = example(x)
println(x_new)
typeof(x_new)
```

Ideal output would be something like this :

```
123
Int32
```

I already tried to solve this problem with parse() or push!() or something like this. But nothing worked well.
I couldn't find a similar problem...

Comment: Include the tag for the language you're working with in future questions — it helps get the attention of those who can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find an issue about adding this functionality to Julia here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/40393

Bottom line, you don't want to use strings, and you should avoid unnecessary exponentiation, both of which will be really slow.

A very brief solution is

```
evalpoly(10, reverse([1,2,3]))
```

Spelling it out a bit more, you can do this

```
function joindigits(xs)
    val = 0
    for x in xs
        val = 10*val + x
    end
    return val
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you need?

```
julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> list2int(x) = sum(10 .^ (length(x)-1:-1:0) .* x)
list2int (generic function with 1 method)

julia> list2int(x)
123
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for string concatenation and then parsing:

```
x_new = parse(Int64, string(x...))
```

Comment: Here `x...` unpacks the array into separate parameters, `string()` will then be called like `string(1, 2, 3)`, becoming "123". You are then parsing this into `Int64`.

Comment: Sure, or a little bit more verbose if someone want other approach:

```julia
parse(Int, join(string.(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting way to convert many small numbers to a bigger one is to combine raw bytes:

```
julia> reinterpret(Int16, [Int8(2),Int8(3)])
1-element reinterpret(Int16, ::Vector{Int8}):
 770
```

Note that 770 = 256*3 + 2

Or for actual `Int`s:

```
julia> reinterpret(Int128, [10,1])
1-element reinterpret(Int128, ::Vector{Int64}):
 18446744073709551626
```

(note that result is exactly `Int128(2)^64+10`)